# May I duplicate my Q/A across multiple SO languagues?

Tags: discussion

I've been thinking. The SO has about **5 million users** on rank. It is not interesting for me to ask anything on SO-portuguese, because there are about **25.000 users** on rank.

I've started to use my SO account about 2 months ago. Last week, I've thought that I could help my local community and created an account on SO-portuguese.

**On SO-pt, it's hard to find a question to my answer. Even harder to find an answer to my question.**

All my questions will be addressed to SO, because I want quick and complete answers. But, may I replicate every question on my local SO-pt?

I really can't see any downside at all, I would only do the work of translator. And, if nobody answer my question on SO-pt, I could just translate the best answer on SO and give the proper credits linked to the original answers. This way, SO-pt will grow with each move I make on SO.

What do you think of this? Is it duplication and wrong or redundancy and right?

Comment: Cross-meta duplicate: [Is it OK to crosspost Stack Overflow questions, now that the Portuguese SO is open?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218055/is-it-ok-to-crosspost-stack-overflow-questions-now-that-the-portuguese-so-is-op).  Hehe.

Answer (score 1):

No one can stop you from doing this, but it's not a great idea.

If answers don't come up in a community organically, we should not artificially create them.

The "best" answer you copy from the original site may evolve over time in the form of edits and comments; there may be late answers that completely replace old ones as technology evolves.

It's very unlikely that you are going to keep track of all these developments, and update them in the Portuguese version of your question as they come up.

Comment: If we are discussing cross posting in the sense of asking questions on both sites at roughly the same time to get more attention and quicker answers, then I am right there with you.  But make a blanket statement to say "no, it should come from the community organically" if you have a known good question with known good answer (as judged by the community via many upvotes), then you are just limiting the research options for programmers who don't speak the language of the origin site.

Comment: @psubsee2003 sure, but who defines "known good question" and "known good answer" exactly? How many upvotes are good enough, and who will police that this won't get abused to farm rep on a new site? What if the original answer is amended, corrected, or overturned? I really don't think translating other people's answers is generally a good way to populate a foreign-language Q&A that can't come up with them itself.